# Is there an alternative to the total commander Change Directory Menu editor?

Tags: total-commander

I'm using the `Change Directory Menu` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)in `Total Commander` a lot.
But my problem is that the editor is terrible and hard to work with - is there an alternative editor (e.g. a plugin someone wrote) that does the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found 2 options - I only tested one.

Option #1 - http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/widimec.html
It is not bad, but a bit limiting - it only knows to edit the wincmd.ini assuming it is under c:\windows. Other than that, works fine.

Option #2 - http://www.utceditors.totalcmd.net/downloads.htm
Looks more professional from the website's POV, but I have not installed it or tried using it.